# Is it possible to order a query by a django model name?

Tags: python, django

I'm using [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to help manage inheritance in some django models, but I'm coming up against a problem.

In short, I have a foreign key that incorporates multiple models through an inheritance type, what I want to know is, is it possible to sort a query based on a model name?

In the below example, is it possible to sort the `buildings` `QuerySet` so that Apartments, Restaurants and Shops are shown in that order?

`models.py`:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    managed_by = fields.ForeignKey(RealEstateAgent)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=100)

class Apartment(Building):
    pass
class Restaurant(Building):
    pass
class Shop(Building):
    pass

class RealEstateAgent(models.Model):
    pass
```

`views.py`:

```
def show_agents_buildings(request,agent):
    buildings = models.Buildings.objects.filter(managed_by=agent).select_subclasses()
    if request.GET.get("sort",None) = "building_type"
        buildings = buildings.order_by("????")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using what is called "multi-table inheritance' or 'concrete inheritance', where one table is created for each model (Building, Apartment, Restaurant and Shop) with an implicit OneToOneField between parent and child. This almost always discouraged since it generates some SQL overhead.

If you don't plan to add extra fields to your *sub-buildings* you'd better add a field `type_` to `Building` with [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) to select the type of building (use `IntegerField` for example, which has a natural ordering). Then you can easily list buildings ordered by that field:

```
buildings = buildings.order_by('type_')
```